# Matching pattern at beginning of line in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I'm working with VIM in git-bash. I have a text file that includes:

```
1  , xxx ,,
2   , yyy ,,
...
```

I tried:

```
:/^.+\,/
```

but this does not match

How can I match and delete this pattern?

Comment: You need to escape the `+` (ie use `\+`) to have it mean "one or more" in vim-regexp. This can be changed using "magic-modes", see `:help magic` for more info on this as well as each character's meaning.

Comment: So you are trying to match a line that contains a comma?

Comment: Also note that `\+` is a greedy match, meaning your search will actually match up till the last comma on the line, not just the first one (which might be what you want, but from your sample data I would guess it isn't). Use `/^.\{-},` if you just want to match up to the first comma on the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete everything up to the first comma, just do:

```
:%s/^[^,]\+,
```

Comment: Can you give a little explanation?

Comment: The command is built this way: `^` from the beginningof the line, `[^,]`any character that is not a comma (`^` means 'not'), `\+` any number (at least one) , `,` up to a comma.